# Making onhover popup box effect like facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

[image]

How to make an onhover popup box effect like on facebook, i don't know how it call so i don't know the keyword to search this.

Comment: Take a look at "http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/" this will help you get started.

Comment: Also look at http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/

Comment: You can amke one using simple HTML/css & JS.

Comment: Actually, you can use only CSS3 without any JavaScript to create popup  boxes ;) (pseudo elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap framework call it a popover

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers

Answer (score 1):

i once needed such a functionality for my site, i used this for my reference

http://papermashup.com/experimental-jquery-tooltips/

or search for jquery tooltips ,,there are thousands of them